# Two obscure MSVC++ 2017 (15.9.28307.905) compiler issues

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, template-specialization

The first issue:

```
#include <iostream>

class Tester
{
public:
    template< typename T >
    static T f1();

    template< typename T >
    static void f2( const T& p = Tester::f1< T >() );
};

template<>
float Tester::f1()
{
    return 0.0f;
}

template< typename T >
void Tester::f2( const T& p )
{
    std::cout << p;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Tester::f2< float >();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compilation output using the aforementioned compiler:

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class $RBAAB __cdecl Tester::f1<`template-type-parameter-1'>(void)" (??$f1@$RBAAB@@Tester@@SA?AV$RBAAB@@XZ) referenced in function main
debug\test.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

MSVC++ 2015 (14.0) reports no errors compiling this code. The error is produced only if `f1` is part of a class. `f2` could be anywhere - a standalone function or a class member one.

If you define `f1` rather than specializing it, that is replace return type `float`:

```
template<>
float Tester::f1()
{
    return 0.0f;
}
```

with `T`:

```
template< typename T >
T Tester::f1()
{
    return 0.0f;
}
```

you'll get the following error:

`error: C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.`

Again MSVC++ 2015 doesn't produce any errors.

Any ideas, why MSVC++ 2017 is more problematic?

Comment: *"An internal error has occurred in the compiler."* is always compiler bug.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Visual Studio 15.9.16, which version do you use? Use Help-About Visual Studio to find out. Which toolset do you use (Project-Properties->General->Platform Toolset)

Comment: Just a note: `template<> T Tester::f1() { ... }` makes no sense, as there's no type `T` defined.

Comment: Also please post the verbatim code the produces the problem instead of writing such as: _if I replace this bit of code with that bit of code..._

Comment: @ivan Had  you followed Jabber's advice, the copy-paste error wouldn't have been there.  And when working with internal compiler errors, we cannot know before hand if your copy-paste errors reflect malformed code or are a copy-paste error.  Every step like that along the way introduces geometric "reasonable decisions" people trying to reproduce your problem have to deal with, any of which could be the cause of your error.  Hence "post verbatim code" and ideally verbatim compiler command lines.  I think MSVC started working on standard compliant 2-phase name lookup: try `/Zc:twoPhase-`

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont As mentioned in my previous comment, which I don't see now for some strange reason, the code is so simple that replacing a small function like this shouldn't be an issue at all. This way you will know that only this little piece has changed, so that to reproduce the next compiler error, and won't be looking in another copy of the code wondering whether something else hasn't changed as well. About the copy-paste error - my bad.

Comment: @Ivan Copy paste errors are inevitable.  Asking questions in a way that is prone to copy-paste errors is not.  You formatted your question in a way that was prone to copy-paste errors (by "here is the change that you should put in the 'obvious' spot").  That was the error, which you seem to think wasn't the error -- having a copy-paste mistake is just something that happens when you choose to make your code copy-paste error prone.  This is why people are asking you *not to format your questions that way*.

Comment: That error may have lost you your chance that someone with a 2017 compiler lying around will see your question and find you an answer.  I don't have one.  I gave my best guess.  Good luck!